# Python создать список списков из обычного списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть, например, список

```
list = [73, 54, 73, 94, -73, -7, -73, 47]
```

Он не фиксированный, то есть значений может быть больше, а может и меньше, но количество элементов всегда кратно 4.

И как мне из этого списка создать вот такой список списков:

```
list = [ [73,54] [73,94] [-73,-7] [-73,47] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_list = [73, 54, 73, 94, -73, -7, -73, 47]

results = [list(couple) for couple in zip(my_list[::2], l[1::2])]

print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

главное чтоб кратно 2 было

просто пройдите через один элемент и выберите пары

способ 1:

```
arr = [73, 54, 73, 94, -73, -7, -73, 47]

res = [[arr[i], arr[i + 1]] for i in range(0, len(arr), 2)]

print(res)
```

способ 2:

```
res = [arr[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(arr), 2)]
```

способ 3:

```
res = list(zip(arr[::2], arr[1::2]))
```